# Maxima of combined cosine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

I'm new to these kinds of functions but I'm interested in mathematical proofs.  Take this function:

$f(x) = 1 - \cos(a x) + \cos(b x)$

I assume this can often have no period, so how do you find the maximum and minimum possible values?

For example, if $a = 0$, then the range of possible values is $[-1, 1]$, and if $b = 0$, then the range is $[1, 3]$.  Unless both equal zero, then $f(x) = 1$.

So the maximum possible range for $f(x)$ is $[-1, 3]$.  But I think with certain values of $a$ and $b$ that this range can be more narrow, just like with $a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

1. If $f(x)$ is aperiodic, is the maximum range $[-1, 3]$ and can this be proven?
2. Can the possible range be proven to be more narrow in certain circumstances and how would this be proven?

Comment: We try to use MathJax here on math.stackexchange to make questions more clear. I edited some of your text, but this has to be approved by someone higher up.

Another note is that range (an interval) is usually written like $[-1,3]$ instead of $\{-1,3\}$, using $\{a,b\}$ is for sets.

Comment: These combinations are still periodic and has a period. For an example see [here.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D1-cos%282x%29%2Bcos%283%2F2x%29) Also local extreme values are given by zeros of the derivative.

Comment: I've approved the edits.  Thank you!

Comment: To answer some of your question. Do you know anything about how to calculate the period of a function, like the function $f(x)=1-\cos(x)+\cos(2x)$? For example, the function $\cos(ax)$ has period $\frac{2\pi }{a}$.

Comment: I don't really understand how to test if a function is periodic or not.  I've seen other posts about using an LCM method but that's as far as I could understand.  I assume if one variable is irrational then it's probably aperiodic by that method.

Comment: @Bumblebee, I might be wrong but isn't the sum periodic here only if $a,b$ are rational? If one of $a,b$ are irrational we might find problems?

Edit: kamikazehighland beat me to it.

Comment: @kamikazehighland: Yes, if at least one of the parameters $a$ or $b$ is irrational this is not periodic. But the function is still bounded and one can compute all maxima/minima explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

For the case $a\ne 0\ne b$ and $b/a\not\in\Bbb Q$:

We have, for $n\in\Bbb Z^+,$ that $f(2\pi n/a)=\cos (2\pi nb/a).$

For any real $y$, let $[y]$ denote the largest integer not exceeding $y.$

Theorem: If $r\in\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$ then $\{nr-[nr]:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is dense in $[0,1].$

From this theorem, with $r=b/a:$ For any $\epsilon\in (0, 1/2)$ there exists $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $$|nb/a-[nb/a]- 1/2|<\epsilon$$ which makes $$-1\le f(2\pi n/a)<-\cos (2\epsilon).$$ Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, therefore $\inf_x f(x)=-1.$

But we cannot have $f(x)=-1$ for any $x,$ as that would require $\cos ax =1$ and $\cos bx=-1,$ which requires $ax/\pi\in\Bbb Z$ and $0\ne bx/\pi\in\Bbb Z,$ (so  also $x\ne 0$), but then $b/a=(bx/\pi)/(ax/\pi)\in\Bbb Q.$

Similarly $\sup_x f(x)=3$ but $f(x)\ne 3$ for any $x.$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x) = 1-\text{cos}(\text{a}x)+\text{cos}(\text{b}x)$. $f’(x) = \text{sin}(\text{a}x)*\text{a}-\text{sin}(\text{b}x)*\text{b}$.
$f’(x)=0$ gives critical values which are often minimums and maximums. So you need to solve when $\text{a}*\text{sin}(\text{a}*x)-\text{b}*\text{sin}(\text{b}*x)=0$. That will tell you where your mins and maxes are. After playing around with different a’s and b’s, I found that when a is $20$ and b is $10$ your max is around $2.125$. And when a and b are switched, your min changes to around $-0.125$. After more playing around, I found that when a is n times b or vice versa you get a different range than $[-1,3]$